# Scala 2.10.6 + Spark 1.6.0: Most appropriate way to map from DataFrame to case classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, case-class

I'm looking for the most appropriate way to map the information contained in a DataFrame to some case classes I've defined, according to the following situation.

I have 2 Hive tables, and a third table which represents the many-to-many relationship between them. Lets call them "Item", "Group", and "GroupItems".
I'm considering executing a single query joining them all, to get the information of a single group, and all its items.
So, each row of the resulting DataFrame, would contain the fields of the Group, and the fields of an Item.

Then, I've created 4 different case classes to use this information in my application. Lets call them:
- ItemProps1: its properties match with some of the Item fields
- ItemProps2: its properties match with some of the Item fields
- Item: contains some properties which match with some of the Item fields, and has 1 object of type ItemProps1, and another of type ItemProps2
- Group: its properties match with the Group fields, and contains a list of items

What I want to do is to map the info contained in the resulting DataFrame into these case classes, but I don't know which would be the most appropriate way.

I know DataFrame has a method "as[U]" which is very useful to perform this kind of mapping, but I'm afraid in my case it wont be useful.

Then, I've found some options to perform the mapping manually, like the following ones:

```
df.map { 
    case Row(foo: Int, bar: String) => Record(foo, bar)
}
```

-

```
df.collect().foreach { row =>
    val foo = row.getAs[Int]("foo")
    val bar = row.getAs[String]("bar")
    Record(foo, bar)
}
```

Is any of these approaches the most appropriate one, or should I do it in another way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Scala 1.6? You can't possibly mean that.

Comment: You're totally right. I've just edited the title. Thanks!